# Excel Pivot Table: use slicer to filter but keep the % difference from previous fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

i have a spreadsheet with about 22000 rows with data. I use a pivot table to count the rows, and i do this by sorting them by month. Then there is another row where i use % difference from previous month.

[image: Excel pivot]

When i use the slicer to filter on months, the % difference is set to zero because they can't compare with previous values.

[image: Excel pivot 2]

Is there a possibility to keep the % difference when using the filter ?

As a solution now i am creating a new table where i copy all values to (=C1, =C2, =C3, ...) and then combine these with the values from other rows but this is too complicated and too much work for such a small problem.

any ideas ?

---

Update:

What i have so far (i'm using 2 excel files, one for the data and another for my power pivot data model and dashboard). I have excel 2016 Pro Plus available at work.

In my first excel file i have a data tab. Each row represents days:

```
Id | Call Date  | Caller
01 | 01/01/2017 | Mark
02 | 01/01/2017 | John
03 | 02/01/2017 | Susan
...
-----------------------
data
```

Then another tab where i make a pivot table based on the data. In this pivot table i can automatically have a months column and have the amount of callers in that month. I can easily select % difference from previous to see the difference in amount of calls.

```
Month | Difference
Jan   | 
Feb   | -14,2%
Mar   | +6,22%
...
-----------------------
%Diff
```

Then in my other excel file i use power pivot to import the excel file. (Get external data) This gives me 2 tables. One for the data (data), one based on the data from the pivot table. (%Diff)

In the data table i have a calculated field with name Month that converts the Call date 01/01/2017 to Jan. I then create a relationship between the two tables where i connect the months.

This works, but i don't want to create pivot tables in my data excel file, i want this as clean as possible and only have it as data source.

*So ... i think the ultimate goal is having a third related table where the colums are Month and %Diff but where the data that goes into these colums come from a pivot table in this file. I tried to create a pivot table, then copy the cells in my data model but can't make any relationships, and i don't know that when my data then updates, the new table updates too :/*

*And .. i don't know if creating a pivot table for this is the right way. Can't it be done straight from the data model ?*

Answer (score 1):

What version of Excel do you have? If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use something called the Data Model to do this. The Data Model allows you to write formulas (called Measures) that you can use inside your PivotTable using an Excel-like formula syntax called DAX. DAX has some pretty handy time-intelligence functions that easily allow you to compare between one period and another.

The higher-end versions of Excel come bundled with a UI called PowerPivot that lets you do a whole bunch of stuff with data in the Data Model. See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-is-Power-Pivot-aa64e217-4b6e-410b-8337-20b87e1c2a4b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) for a listing of what versions the PowerPivot addin ships with. But you can still write DAX Measures using lower-end versions even without the PowerPivot addin, as demonstrated by Mike Girvin's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVVK-8QZC1M).

Comment: I'm using excel 2010. I will look onto the video and see if i can find what i'm looking for. Thanks !

Comment: Okay, for 2010 you'll have to actually download and install the PowerPivot addin. I think an easier solution will be to continue down the path you have, and make use of an unfiltered PivotTable and the GETPIVOTDATA function so that you can still reference the last month's data point from the unfiltered table. Late here, but I'll see if I can whip up an example tomorrow.

Comment: That would be nice thans, cracking my head over this.

Comment: Couple of questions: Why is there no figure for January? Is it because you have no data for the previous December, or is it because you couldn't figure out a way to reference the December data? And are your dates all strings (i.e. the words "jan", "feb", etc) or is there another field in the PivotTable that actually stores these as numerical dates?

Comment: Hi, there is no figure for january because it's the first month, so nothing to compare. Thank me for the song playing in your head all day :)

My dates are date fields like this: 

    '1/01/2017 0:02:05
    1/01/2017 0:04:07
    2/01/2017 0:04:18'

So they got grouped by month automatically after making the pivot table.

Comment: So will there only be data in this pivot from one year? Or will you keep adding data in it, so that next January you will need to compare against the previous December?

Comment: I want to keep adding data

Comment: Okay, let me put my kids to bed, and then have a think and come back with a solution.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my question with what i have got so far. I don't know if i'm doing it right so any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to solve it thanks to @jeffreyweir for pointing me in the right direction. I used the Data model to create my database with my Incidents Table and a Date table (basically a Calendar helper table), then created 3 measures with DAX formulas.

The first measure just counts the total number of entries in the row call number:

```
Number of Incidents:=COUNTA(Incidents[Call Number])
```

Then i create a measure that displays the value of the previous month:

```
Incidents SPLM:=IF([Number of Incidents]<>0;CALCULATE(COUNTA(Incidents[Call Number]);PREVIOUSMONTH(Calendar[Date]));BLANK())
```

Then created a third measure that Calculates the % difference from the previous month:

```
Inc % Diff:=IF[Incidents SPLM]<>0;([Number Of Incidents]/[Incidents SPLM])-1;BLANK())
```

et voila

Comment: Cool. Given I solved the issue, can you please accept my answer?